# Impulse and momentum on a system of three particles (equilateral triangle)

Tags: homework-and-exercises, angular-momentum, momentum, rotational-dynamics

I found this exercise on a textbook which provided solely the description of what is happening and the answers with little explanation. The solution being provided, I am mostly interested in understanding what is happening. Consider the following system composed of three particles, each of mass $m$, connected by rigid massless rods in the form of an equilateral triangle. The system is initially at rest (particle $A$ is above particle $B$ in the initial state). An impulse $\hat{F}$ is applied to $A$, causing the particle $B$ to slide without friction on a supporting base.

[image]

The idea is to solve for the values of $\dot x$ and $\dot \theta$ velocities immediately after the impulse; and evaluate the constraint impulse $\hat{N}$.

My initial idea was to use the linear impulse, focusing in the $x$ direction first. Since particle B will be sliding, the linear acceleration of the system would be $3m\ddot x$. By taking particle B as the reference point, and since the system center of mass would be engaged in an arc motion, its acceleration $x$ component (tangential) directly after the impulse would be $ml\sqrt{3}\ddot\theta$ (the radius would be $l/\sqrt{3}$).

So the impulse would be $\hat{F}=3m\dot x+ml\sqrt{3}\dot \theta$.

But the textbook solution indicates that $\hat{F}=3m\dot x+\frac{3}{2}ml\dot \theta$.

So my first problem is: where does the $\frac{3}{2}$ comes from? Or am I working this completely wrong?

Upon seeing this solution I wondered if perhaps this $\frac{3}{2}ml\ddot \theta$ tangential component of angular acceleration would be the result of the addition of an $l/2$ radius (along the vertical axis) which would be the vertical distance towards particle C from B; plus the $l$ radius which would be the vertical distance towards particle $A$; multiplied by $\ddot \theta$. Which would result in a "tangential" component along the $x$ axis of $\frac{3}{2}ml\ddot \theta$. Would this be an acceptable proposition?

My idea was then to state the angular impulse as the variation of the angular momentum, resulting in the multiplication of $\hat{F}$ by the distance between particle $B$ and the center of mass: $l/\sqrt{3}$. This way I would end up with a system of two equations and two variables and solve for $\dot x$ and $\dot \theta$.

Only, again the solution provided is rather far from my idea because it states that $\hat{F}l = \frac{3}{2}ml\dot x + 2ml^2\dot \theta$. And I see little relationship with the linear impulse equation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This question did not get up votes nor answers, maybe because as it turns out, this was not that complicated. In any case, I still propose a detailed answer just in case.

**Solving for $\dot x$ and $\dot \theta$**

The impulse applied on top would be defined as the variation in the linear momentum of the particles system. For more convenience, we will be using particle $B$ as a reference point.

\begin{equation}
  \hat{\mathbf{J}} = \sum\limits_{i=1}^{3}\Delta \mathbf{p_i}
\end{equation}

where $\hat{\mathbf{J}}$ is the total impulse vector affecting the system, comprised of the horizontal $\hat{F}$ and the vertical constraint impulse $\hat{N}$; and $\sum\limits_{i=1}^{3}\Delta \mathbf{p_i}$ is the sum of the linear momentum variation of the system particles. Since the system is *initially at rest*, its particles initial velocities are null, so the linear momentum variation is simply the sum of their individual final momenta.

Because particles $A$ and $C$ are subject to a linear velocity $\dot x$ resulting from the sliding of particle $B$; and to an angular velocity $\dot\theta$ resulting from the rotation about particle $B$; the above equation can then be developed as:

\begin{equation}
  \left(\hat{F}\,\vec{i}+\hat{N}\,\vec{j}\right) = m\left( \left( -l\frac{\sqrt{3}}{2}\vec{i} + \frac{l}{2}\vec{j} \right) \times \dot\theta\vec{k} + \dot x\vec{i} \right) + m\left( l\vec{j} \times \dot\theta\vec{k} + \dot x\vec{i} \right) + m\dot x\vec{i}
\end{equation}

where $\vec{i}$, $\vec{j}$ and $\vec{k}$ are unit vectors of the frame and the $\times$ operator denotes the cross product between vectors. On the right hand side of the above equation, the first term corresponds to the linear momentum of particle $C$, the middle one corresponds to the linear momentum of particle $A$ and the last term is the linear momentum of particle $B$ which is only subject to a sliding motion.

By developing the above equation, the $\hat{F}$ and $\hat{N}$ components of the applied linear impulse vector $\hat{\mathbf{J}}$ are identified as the horizontal linear impulse applied on particle $A$:

\begin{equation}
 \hat{F} = 3m\dot x + \frac{3}{2}m l \dot\theta
\end{equation}

and the constraint linear impulse applied by the supporting base on particle $B$:

\begin{equation}
 \hat{N} = \frac{\sqrt{3}}{2}m l \dot\theta
\end{equation}

Since the constraint linear impulse $\hat{N}$ is considered a consequence of the linear impulse $\hat{F}$ and the value of $\hat{N}$ is unknown, we still need one equation to solve for the $\dot x$ and $\dot \theta$ values. Keeping particle $B$ as the reference point for the *angular* momentum of each particle, we can find $\dot x$ and $\dot \theta$ without having to solve for $\hat{N}$. Thus, we can state a relationship between the *angular impulse* at $B$ resulting from the linear impulse on particle $A$ and the variation of the angular momentum of each particle:

\begin{equation}
  \hat{\mathbf{M}} = \sum\limits_{i=1}^{3}\Delta \mathbf{H_i} = \sum\limits_{i=1}^{3}\mathbf{r}_i \times \Delta \mathbf{p_i}
\end{equation}

where $\hat{\mathbf{M}}$ stands for the angular impulse around particle $B$ of the linear impulse $\hat{F}$ applied on $A$;  $\sum\limits_{i=1}^{3}\Delta \mathbf{H_i}$ represents the sum of the individual angular momenta around $B$ of particles $A$ and $C$; and $\mathbf{r}_i$ is the vector going from $B$ to the other particles.

On the left hand side of the above equation we have

\begin{equation}
  \hat{\mathbf{M}} = \hat{F}\,\vec{i} \times l\vec{j} = \hat{F}l\vec{k}
\end{equation}

and on the right hand side, since the initial velocities  we have:

\begin{equation}
  \sum\limits_{i=1}^{3}\mathbf{r}_i \times \Delta \mathbf{p_i} = \left( -l\frac{\sqrt{3}}{2}\vec{i} + \frac{l}{2}\vec{j} \right) \times \left( m\left( \frac{l}{2}\dot\theta + \dot x \right)\vec{i} + ml\theta\frac{\sqrt{3}}{2}\vec{j} \right) + l\vec{j} \times m(l\dot\theta + \dot x)\vec{i}
\end{equation}

where the first cross product stands for the angular momentum of particle $C$ around $B$; and the second cross product stands for the angular momentum of particle $A$ around $B$. By developing this last equation with that of $\hat{M}$ just before it, we find that

\begin{equation}
 \hat{F}l = \frac{3}{2}ml\dot x + 2ml^2\dot\theta 
\end{equation}

Thus, by recalling the *horizontal linear impulse equation* while forming a system with the above equation,

\begin{equation}
 \hat{F} = 3m\dot x + \frac{3}{2}m l \dot\theta
\end{equation}

we can solve for the values of $\dot x$ and $\dot\theta$:

\begin{equation}
 \dot\theta = \frac{2\hat{F}}{5ml}
\end{equation}

and

\begin{equation}
 \dot x = \frac{2\hat{F}}{15ml}
\end{equation}

**Solving for the value of the constraint linear impulse $\hat{N}$**

By recalling the *vertical linear impulse equation* previously obtained

\begin{equation}
 \hat{N} = \frac{\sqrt{3}}{2}m l \dot\theta
\end{equation}

and by injecting the value of the angular velocity $\dot\theta$ just above:

\begin{equation}
 \hat{N} = \frac{\sqrt{3}}{5}\hat{F}
\end{equation}